# Custom Post Type urls not working

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type functionality defined on my website for a certain action. In order to achieve a specific type of url structure. I removed the constant slug from it and replaced it with category and brand name.

The previous url was

www.website.com/product/name

The new url is

www.website.com/category/brand/name

You see, I have totally removed the slug. Here is the code for that. Now the issue is that these urls are not working and I am geting a 404 page in return. I have tried flushing the permailinks as well but it is not helping.

According to my understanding because of removing the slug, the query is searching in 'Post' not the 'Custom Post Type' but I don't know how to correct it. You response will be highly appreciated.

```
// Register our Custom Post type as aps-products
public static function register_cpt_aps_products() {
    $permalinks = get_aps_settings('permalinks');
    $slug = (isset($permalinks['product-slug'])) ? $permalinks['product-slug'] : '';

    // labels text for our post type aps-products
    $labels = array(
        // post type general name
        'name' => __( 'APS Products', 'aps-text' ),
        // post type singular name
        'singular_name' => __( 'APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'name_admin_bar' => __( 'APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'APS Products', 'aps-text' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'archives' => __( 'APS Products Archives', 'aps-text' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search APS Products', 'aps-text' ),
        'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insert into APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'featured_image' => __( 'APS Product Image', 'aps-text' ),
        'set_featured_image' => __( 'Set APS Product Image', 'aps-text' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove APS Product Image', 'aps-text' ),
        'use_featured_image' => __( 'Use as APS Product image', 'aps-text' ),
        'not_found' =>  __( 'No APS Products found', 'aps-text' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No APS Products found in Trash', 'aps-text' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-products',
        'capability_type' => 'aps-products',
        'capabilities' => array(
           'read_post' => 'read_aps_product',
           'edit_post' => 'edit_aps_product',
           'edit_posts' => 'edit_aps_products',
           'delete_posts' => 'delete_aps_products',
           'create_posts' => 'create_aps_products',
           'publish_posts' => 'publish_aps_products',
           'edit_published_posts' => 'edit_published_aps_products',
           'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_aps_products',
           'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_aps_products',
           'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_aps_products',
           'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_aps_products',
           'edit_private_posts' => 'edit_private_aps_products',
           'delete_private_posts' => 'delete_private_aps_products'
        ),
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','aps-cats', 'aps-brands', 'aps-attributes', 'aps-filters', 'aps-rating-bars'),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => 'aps-products',
        'supports' => array( 'publicize','title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'author', 'excerpt' ),
        'register_meta_box_cb' => array(__CLASS__, 'add_aps_products_metabox'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/%aps-cats%/%aps-brands%/', 'with_front' => false)
    );
```

Comment: Didn't look into your code bc no time, but did you save your permalinks after changing the functions.php? Everytime you change a permalink structure (like the one of your CPT) you have to go to "Settings" -> "Permalinks" and click save.

Comment: Yes. I did save. 

Here is the screenshot of request and how it is only searching in 'post'. prntscr.com/gfrm31 Brand and Category are already APS taxonomies and defined.

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting > permalinks and save it, then open www.website.com/category/brand/name

Comment: Perhaps you could explain a little bit more how this would solve OP's question?

Comment: It is a custom post type. I flushed permailinks.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your rewrite slug. you can try somthing like this.

```
    add_action('init', 'create_brand');
    function create_brand()
    {

    register_taxonomy
    (
        'sumo-brand-letter',
        array(),
        array
        (
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array
            (
                'name' => _x('Letters', 'taxonomy general name'),
                'singular_name' => _x('Letter', 'taxonomy singular name')
                # And so one
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => 'brand-letter',
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'brand',
            ),
        )
    );

    register_post_type
    (
        'sumo-brand-term',
        array
        (
            'labels' => array
            (
                'name' => _x('Brand Terms', 'post type general name'),
                'singular_name' => _x('Brand Term', 'post type singular name')
                # And so on …
            ),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'public' => true,
            'rewrite' => array
            (
                'slug' => 'brand/%sumo-brand-letter%',
                'with_front' => false

            ),
            'query_var' => 'brand-term',
            'has_archive' => 'brand',
            'taxonomies' => array( 'sumo-brand-letter' ),
        )
    );
    }

    add_filter('post_type_link', 'brand_term_permalink', 10, 4);
    function brand_term_permalink($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample)
    {
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%sumo-brand-letter%' ) ) {
        $brand_letter = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'sumo-brand-letter' );
        $post_link = str_replace( '%sumo-brand-letter%', array_pop( $brand_letter )->slug, $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
    }
```

Comment: Here is the screenshot of request and how it is only searching in 'post'. 

http://prntscr.com/gfrm31

Brand and Category are already APS taxonomies and defined.